# Adjust RMMarker to user's current location automatically in oflline maps using MBTiles

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios7, mapbox

Can i adjust RMMarker to user's current location using MBTiles without tapping on map? Is there any method or API to achieve this in mapbox without WiFi/3G? I just wanted to move RMMarker along with user just like in google maps.

Answer (score 1):

You will probably want to use `-[RMMapView setUserTrackingMode:]`, which uses Core Location and can operate with just the GPS even when offline (though with less accuracy).

Answer (score 0):

Use setLocation:location method we get Latitude longitude while moving using Cellular data. The marker follows the location.