# How to interact with RMMBTilesSource using mapbox SDK

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios7, mapbox

I am new to mapbox and trying to implement offline maps on iOS.I generated MBTiles and able to load it on iPhone. But i am not getting how to interact with MBTiles i.e how to add markers on MBTiles without WiFi/3G and how to move RMMarker to users current location without WiFi/3G. Is it possible to achieve this using MapBox and GPS chip on?

I went through android app [MMapFactor: GPS Navigation](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.mapfactor.navigator) which uses openstreetmapdata to show user current location without WiFi/3G. Is it possible to achieve that functionality in iOS world using MapBox SDK? Is there any other alternatives other than MapBox?

Answer (score 0):

I answered the first part of your question over in your other post at [Adjust RMMarker to user's current location automatically in oflline maps using MBTiles](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25880687/adjust-rmmarker-to-users-current-location-automatically-in-oflline-maps-using-m/25897256#25897256). To add markers, yes, you can still place them as long as you have a coordinate at which to do so. They don't require internet access as long as you use your own custom imagery or pre-download (or bundle) marker images to use when offline. If you use the Mapbox markers API, any marker images that you fetch when offline will be cached for offline use.

Answer (score 0):

It is very much possible and easy with MAPBOX. Follow below steps

1) After Importing MBTile File to App, Use SingleTapOnMap Method and get Latitude & Longitude

2) With this use MySQL get tile_column,tile_row and Zoom_levels

3)Use RMInteractiveSourceNormalizedTilePointForMapView  and  InteractivityDictionaryForTilePoint:inMapView, get key_json values and will keep the marker at place which we tap.

4) Use setLocation:location method we get Latitude longitude while moving using Cellular data. The marker follows the location.